# Displaying static image in Django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-staticfiles, django-settings

If the user has a profile picture, I would like to display it. If he/she does not have a profile picture, I would like to display a default image in it's place.

Is there a way to load a static image in a Django model property?

*Note: The user's profile picture loads with the following code. The `else` statement containing the default image does not work.*

This is what I have so far:

***models.py:***

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    profile_picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='user/profile_pictures/', 
                                    null=False, 
                                    blank=False)

    @property
    def default_profile_picture(self):
        if self.profile_picture:
            return "%s/%s" %(settings.MEDIA_URL, self.profile_picture)
        else:
            return settings.STATIC_URL + 'img/default_profile_picture.jpg'
```

***settings.py:***

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_dirs"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), "static", "static_root")
```

Thank you in advance for all of your help!

Answer (score 1):

A few things you need to check:

1. Did you set MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL in your **settings.py** file?
2. You have a upload_to specified:

   ```
   upload_to='user/profile_pictures/'
   ```

   Is this path under the MEDIA_ROOT path? (i.e. discoverable by Django)
3. You have to tell Django to serve the static files by adding the following lines in your **urls.py** file:

   ```
   from django.conf import settings
   from django.conf.urls.static import static

   urlpatterns = [
       # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
   ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```

   The code above is for Django 1.8. For your version of django, read the documentation here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/
4. In production, you should let Apache or nginx to server static images. The method recommended in step 2 is only used for development and testing purpose.
5. If you have done all of the steps above and it still does not work, find the link to the profile image in the rendered webpage, copy and paste it into a browser window and see what kind of error comes up.

Comment: Thank you for this, but I was referring to the default image under the `STATIC_URL`, not the `MEDIA_URL`. That is why I did not include my media configuration - it is irrelevant to this question. I also want to display the image directly from the model, not from a rendered webpage.

Comment: @jape it doesn't matter if you are loading the image from the MEDIA dir or the STATIC dir, the steps of making this happen is the same. 1. Django has to be able to discover the images. 2. Django or whatever server you choose has to serve these images. Since your default profile image is static, there is no need to load it into your model. You can write an if..else to check whether the current user has an profile image. It he/she has it, great load it up. If not, just link to your default image like how you would load a css file in a template.